# JSON Model and Skeletal Animation skewed/distorted/stretched

Tags: three.js

I'm having trouble animating JSON models, exported from blender, in Three.js and it's been holding me up for a while.

I have a mesh, with bones, automatic weighting and vertex groups, and a simple test animation which works fine in blender, but when played in the browser it appears stretched etc. In this case some faces are missing also despite having 'Double Sided' selected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6NxK.jpg

I've been googling for a few days and can't seem to find a solution which works for me

Things I've tried:

- Exporting at frame 0
- Exporting at rest pose
- Unparenting armature from mesh
- Parenting with auto weights/envolope weights
- Rotating 90degrees before animating
- Resetting position/rotation/scale
- Removed armature modifier
- Multiple models/animations from google
- All the things the first few pages of google returns

(temporary) links:

```
demo:http://82.199.155.77/prisontest.html
.blend file: http://82.199.155.77/content/models/animated/humanoid_base_01/humanoid_base_01.blend
```

code:

```
    var modelloader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    modelloader.load('/content/models/animated/humanoid_base_01/humanoid_base_01.js', 
    function (geometry, materials) 
    {
        var modelMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
        for(var i = 0; i < modelMaterial.materials.length; i++)
        {
            modelMaterial.materials[i].skinning = true;
        }

        var modelMesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, modelMaterial);
        modelMesh.position.x = 3500;
        modelMesh.position.y = 50;
        modelMesh.position.z = 3500;
        //modelMesh.rotateY(90);
        modelMesh.scale.set(100, 100, 100);
        scene.add(modelMesh);

        THREE.AnimationHandler.add(modelMesh.geometry.animations[0]);
        animation = new THREE.Animation(modelMesh, "Walk01", THREE.AnimationHandler.CATMULLROM);
        animation.play();
    });
```

Update:

After days of trying to get animations to work properly, I've given up. It appears there's a bug either in the Three.js blender exporter, or the animation code itself. Hopefully this will be fixed soon. In the mean time, I'm left with this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNaHi.png

Comment: This is only a guess: three.js no longer supports quad faces.

Comment: Converted quads to tris, no effect (Blender knowledge is limited, may have done it incorrectly). thanks though.